# SimpleXML, trying to loop through elements and create associative array out of values

Tags: php, simplexml

I can't get SimpleXML to work as I need it too. I want to create an associative array out of elements. Here's what xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RateV4Response>
<Package ID="1">
<ZipOrigination>11901</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>91730</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>0</Pounds>
<Ounces>3.5</Ounces>
<Size>REGULAR</Size>
<Machinable>TRUE</Machinable>
<Zone>8</Zone>

<Postage CLASSID="3">
    <MailService>Express Mail</MailService>
    <Rate>28.00</Rate>
</Postage>
<Postage CLASSID="2">
    <MailService>Express Mail Hold For Pickup</MailService>
    <Rate>28.00</Rate>
</Postage>
```

MailService and Rate should be an array.
This is my php:

```
$usps_response = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
foreach($usps_response->Package->Postage as $service)
    $data[] = array($service->MailService => $service->Rate);
```

I don't see an error here, but $data is 28 empty elements. I also tried this:

```
$data[] = array($service['MailService'] => $service['Rate']);
```

but that didn't help

If I assign just $service to $data[], then I see 28 elements with 3 sub-elements each (attributes, MailService and Rate).

What am I doing wrong?

Here are pics to help see the data
[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be a matter of trying to use an object as an array, instead of just using it as an object.  I'll try to show you what I might do with that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems odd you want a key like `Express Mail Hold For Pickup` in your array but here we go:

```
foreach($usps_response->Package->Postage as $service)
    $data[] = array((string)$service->MailService => (string)$service->Rate);
```

Comment: thank you! It works now! So what does (string) do? Convert objects!?

Comment: you're welcome! it does typecasting (refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php for more info) also you might want to (float)$service->Rate

Comment: Specifically, SimpleXML objects have special behaviour when cast to a string, which "flattens" the text content of the XML node. Unfortunately, @godka is wrong to suggest `(float)`, since an oddity of PHP's internals means that SimpleXML interprets this as `(int)`, so would lose any pence.

Answer (score 1):

The XML posted here is not valid XML, so I have to assume that it is either incomplete or the postal service produced something that was not very useful.  With a few changes, I was able to make it work.  Please see 
http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_user193.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_user193.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

// TEST DATA
$xml = <<<ENDXML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RateV4Response>
<Package ID="1">
<ZipOrigination>11901</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>91730</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>0</Pounds>
<Ounces>3.5</Ounces>
<Size>REGULAR</Size>
<Machinable>TRUE</Machinable>
<Zone>8</Zone>

<Postage CLASSID="3">
    <MailService>Express Mail</MailService>
    <Rate>28.00</Rate>
</Postage>
<Postage CLASSID="2">
    <MailService>Express Mail Hold For Pickup</MailService>
    <Rate>28.00</Rate>
</Postage>
</Package>
</RateV4Response>
ENDXML;

// MAKE AN OBJECT
$obj = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml);
var_dump($obj);
```

Now what would you like to do with this object?

Comment: This produces the same exact result as I had before. XML provided was partial, to give an idea of what I'm working with.

Comment: Please don't provide "partial XML" -- at least give us something that will parse correcttly.  It wastes your time if we cannot move forward toward answers based on your content.